# Collocation configuration using readthrough (DB persistance)

Tags: datagridview, ignite, gridgain

embedded ignite, with db persistence configured, writethrough disabled, readthrough enabled. using CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory as cache store factory. example for a table:

**personTable**

int id //primary key

String name

String lastName

int cityId

cache definition is <Integer, Person>. the problem is that affinity can be used for keys like:

**PersonKey**

int id //primary key

@AffinityKeyMapped

int cityId

and not pure Integer.
Cache store is "auto" populated (cache.load) using the jdbc driver and I have no control over the key/data in terms of manipulation - I cannot manipulate them (and if I did, I assume the readthrough capability will be damaged).

`type.setKeyType(Integer.class); type.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "id", int.class, "id"))`

Should I just change this to that?
`type.setKeyType(PersonKey.class); type.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.INTEGER, "id", PersonKey.class, "id"))`

what should I do with QueryEntity, I still want to be able to query using the id only?

```
    QueryEntity qryEntity = new QueryEntity();

    qryEntity.setKeyType(?????);

    qryEntity.setValueType(Person);

    qryEntity.setTableName(PersonTable);

    qryEntity.setKeyFieldName(??????);
```

is that only the table representation and can keep using the Integer id here?

Can anyone suggest a way to manipulate the current Integer key and use PersonKey instead while preserving the readthrough capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

First, your table needs to be `<PersonKey,Person>`.

Second, I'd suggest using annotations rather than query entities. (You *can* do it using query entities, but since you're already using an annotation this is the simplest route.)

```
class PersonKey {
    @QuerySqlField(index=true)
    private int id;
    @QuerySqlField
    @AffinityKeyMapped
    private int cityId;
}
```

Then the same again for your Person class.

When you create your table, you do `.setIndexedTypes(PersonKey.class, Person.class)` and it'll enable the SQL for you.

If you want to access the table using the `id` rather than the whole key, you'll need to use a SQL query.

Comment: thx! that clear. my problem is that I want to keep using key\value api without affinity key (just the id itself). I tried to use AffinityKey<Integer> but i noticed that key/value api search for a complete match of both key and affinity key. I need the key/value api to take advantage of the readthrough capability when I want to load new entity in the DB to the cache. I use 'get' and because its not in the cache its been loaded from db - the problem is that using AffinityKey I must also provide the initial affinity key value (in addition to the id) to have a match... anyway to overcome?

Comment: is there a way to map object by affinity but still working with original integer key? or maybe use AffinityKey but somehow ignore the affinity key value and use the id only. btw - i've noticed that (unfortunately) key/value api doesnt use AffinityKey.equals, seems like there is some wrapper KeyCacheObject, otherwise the AffinityKey.equals would have found a match. ideas pls?